# How to separate data per column when writing data to excel from web scraping results

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know how to separate it when the data looks like:

```
x, y, z
```

But I can't figure out how to do it when the data format is like:

```
Doe, John, BookName, Year, abstract with commas, links.
```

[This is what the data looks like in excel after the scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06xG4.png)
[This is what i wanted it to looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs383.png)
This is my code

```
from unittest import result
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib3.request
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


fakdep = '165'  
offset = input('Please enter number of offset:')
url = 'https://repositori.usu.ac.id/handle/123456789/{}?offset={}'.format(fakdep,offset)
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

datas = []
count_page = 0
for page in range(1,2): 
    count_page+=1
    print('Scraping Offset No:', count_page)
    result = requests.get(url+str(page), verify=False) 
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('li','ds-artifact-item')
    for it in items:
        author = it.find('span','author h4').text
        title = ''.join(it.find('a',href=True).text.strip().split('\n'))
        year = it.find('span','date').text
        abstract = ''.join(it.find('div','artifact-abstract').text.strip().split('\n'))
        link = it.find('a')['href']
        datas.append([author, title, year, abstract, link])

kepala = ['Author', 'Title', 'Year', 'Abstract', 'Link']
thewriter = csv.writer(open('results/{}_{}.csv'.format(fakdep,offset), 'w', newline=''))
thewriter.writerow(kepala)
for d in datas: thewriter.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Please make this into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your code can actually be tested~

Comment: for page in range(1, 2): this loop will only be executed once because range(1, 2) means 1 to 1. Range(1, 3) means 1 to 2 and so on...

Comment: What offset is needed to be entered by a user to run this code? One or two examples might be enough.

Comment: Yes, i only need to execute the code once for test. Any offset is fine, even 0. The website use offset to move the list. for example, the page show 20 list per page (1, 2, 3... 20) offset 1 will make (2, 3, 4...21). Thank you very much for the suggestion, will try to implement that. Sorry for the lack of info needed to run the code, even after i've been told before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion. I will need to know an offset to be able to test it.

A CSV separated by semi-colons will be far easier to separate in Excel.

```py
from unittest import result
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib3.request
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


fakdep = '165'  
offset = input('Please enter number of offset:')
url = 'https://repositori.usu.ac.id/handle/123456789/{}?offset={}'.format(fakdep,offset)
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

datas = []
count_page = 0
for page in range(1,2): 
    count_page+=1
    print('Scraping Offset No:', count_page)
    result = requests.get(url+str(page), verify=False) 
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('li','ds-artifact-item')
    for it in items:
        author = it.find('span','author h4').text
        title = ''.join(it.find('a',href=True).text.strip().replace('/n', ''))
        year = it.find('span','date').text
        abstract = ''.join(it.find('div','artifact-abstract').text.strip().replace('/n', ''))
        link = it.find('a')['href']
        datas.append([author, title, year, abstract, link])

kepala = ['Author', 'Title', 'Year', 'Abstract', 'Link']
thewriter = csv.writer(open('results/{}_{}.csv'.format(fakdep,offset), 'w', newline=''), delimiter=";")
thewriter.writerow(kepala)
for d in datas: thewriter.writerow(d)
```

Comment: I've added a comment on my first post addressing the offset. I immediately try to implement the two changes that you suggest, and it works, and i got what i wanted it to looks like. Thank you very much for the help. Very appreciated.